# is it compatible the left crank arm of ultegra 6600 with ultegra 6800?

Tags: crankset

I would like to buy a power meter and the nearest I found to my shimano ultegra 6600 crankset is the ultegra 6800 left crank arm. It is the same size though.
many thanks

Comment: Other than an optical difference there is no functional difference. Just be sure to acquire the correct length.

Answer (score 3):

Both the 6600 series and the 6800 series use the same diameter spindle(24mm). The interface is Shimano standard Hollowtech II.